# Multiplos de 3 entre 2 y 20 PHP

Tags: php, php7, php5

Me gustaría saber como puedo realizar una funcion para sacar **los multiplos de 3 entre los numeros 2 y 20**

No tengo muy claro todavía el tema de las funciones porque estoy comenzando a ello, por si alguien puede echar una mano.

Hasta el momento tengo esto:

```
for ($i = 2; $i <= 20; $i++) {
    echo $i; 
    if($i%3==0) {
       echo $i%3
    }
    else 
        break;
```

Comment: ¿Qué es lo que llevas hecho? ¿Dónde te has atascado? Sube el código que tengas para poder tener un punto de partida desde el que ayudarte.

Comment: Te podemos echar una una mano, pero da tú el primer paso...  ¿Has investigado algo? ¿Has intentado algo en base a lo investigado? ¿Qué dificultades tienes en eso que has intentado? Es que si no, parecería que pides que hagan el código por ti y el propósito no es ese.

Comment: Pues hasta ahora no llevo hecho mas que la declaracion de variables que sería a=2 b=20 y c=3 siendo c el valor del que quiero sacar los multiplos y a y b los valores entre los que se comprende

Comment: Bien, ese es ya un primer paso. Ahora puedes pasarle esos datos a una función, abres un bucle que empiece en `a` y llegue hasta `b` y dentro del bucle verificas si cada valor es múltiplo de `c`... Ya tienes el enunciado, ahora te toca averiguar cómo se abre un bucle y cómo se verifica si un número es múltiplo de otro. Son cosas básicas de programación. Haz el intento y si te atascas te ayudaremos. El propósito es que investigues por ti mismo y aprendas, si te lo damos hecho no vas a aprender cosas básicas que se aprenden investigando.

Comment: No se si lo que he actualizado estaría correcto

Answer (score 3, accepted):

El código está casi bien. Sólo que si pones un `break` el bucle se va a detener cuando lo encuentre. Si se trata de comprobar todos debes agotar todas la iteracciones.

Aquí te dejo una función que calcularía qué números entre `$from` y `$to` son múltiplos de `$toCheck`, devolviéndote un array solamente con los valores que son múltiplos.

```
function getMultiplos($from, $to, $toCheck)
{
    $allMultiplos=array();
    for ($i = $from; $i <= $to; $i++) 
    {
        if($i%$toCheck==0) {
          $allMultiplos[]=$i;
          echo "$i multiplo de $toCheck".PHP_EOL;
        }
        else
        {
           echo "$i no multiplo de $toCheck".PHP_EOL;
        }
    }
    return $allMultiplos;
}
```

Los `echo`  son sólo para prueba, luego los puedes quitar.

Veamos una prueba:

```
$from=2;
$to=20;
$toCheck=3;

$arr=getMultiplos($from, $to, $toCheck);
print_r($arr);
#Puedes usar $arr para lo que necesites
```

**Salida:**

Los `echo` van a imprimir:

```
2 no multiplo de 3
3 multiplo de 3
4 no multiplo de 3
5 no multiplo de 3
6 multiplo de 3
7 no multiplo de 3
8 no multiplo de 3
9 multiplo de 3
10 no multiplo de 3
11 no multiplo de 3
12 multiplo de 3
13 no multiplo de 3
14 no multiplo de 3
15 multiplo de 3
16 no multiplo de 3
17 no multiplo de 3
18 multiplo de 3
19 no multiplo de 3
20 no multiplo de 3
```

Y el array resultante sería:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 3
    [1] => 6
    [2] => 9
    [3] => 12
    [4] => 15
    [5] => 18
)
```

Quizá habría que establecer otros controles en la función, como verificar que `$from`, `$to` y `$toCheck` son números, que `$from` es menor que `$to`  y que `$toCheck` es un número positivo. Eso lo dejo a tu cuidado.

Comment: @Marcos sí, ya lo hice. Olvidé usar las variables dentro de la función, lo mismo pasaba con el `for`. Ya está corregido. Gracias.